Return one value from a report list, not sum or record count in Sheets
I am trying to use a formula to return one value from a list of record counts.
Here is the example so you all know what I mean.
What I am trying to do is return in one field the amount of sold software per rep, which I do with the formula SUMIFS. I also know how to return the amount of record types for a certain value using COUNTIFS.
However, the quota is different every month and in my report list the month could appear several times. So for example I have 4 record types of May, which all reflect the quota of that rep for that month. In a field (see exercise linked) I want to return that quota but only one time. I can't do it with COUNTIFS or SUMIFS.
I could count SUMIFS of all and then divide it by the COUNTIFS...but there must be a simpler way?
Thankful for any help I can get!

EDIT:
You can use the formula below for the employee "Susan" and drag down.
=IFERROR(INDEX(FILTER(D$2:F,D$2:D=K$3,C$2:C=J5),1,3),"")


This is solving what I already have on my sheet and did with SUMIFS (Linked exercise). I am not trying to get the sum of what they sold, I am just trying to return one value (their quota for that month), even though the quota and that month is in the report multiple times.

See the "EDIT" in my answer please, if it helps. Otherwise, give some expected results to understand the question.

This is summing up the values. I can do this with SUMIFs. I can also count the number of times a value appears using COUNTIFs. So this is not what I am looking for. I updated the sheet and added the expected result for the quota. Susan's quota for May appears 2 times in the report, each showing 100k. This doesn't mean that her quota is 200k. It means her quota for May is 100k, no matter how often it appears. Your formula is just summing this up to show 200k, but I am looking for a formula that returns one value for the monthly quota no matter how many times it appears.

After the expected results, i understod the problem finally... :) Please see the EDIT in my answer once again.

Thank you so so much. This is basically what I wanted. I just changed the exercise sheet now to reflect dates rather than month names. Is it possible to do this using your formula but including a date range in the search?

Can you try this? =IFERROR(INDEX(FILTER(F$2:F;A$2:A=K$3;Month(D$2:D)=Month(J5));1);"") You may need to change semicolons to commas depending on your settings. And, if your problem is solved you may consider accepting the answer

And, another alternative is using the start and end dates in columns I & J is; =IFERROR(INDEX(FILTER(F$2:F;A$2:A=K$3;(D$2:D>=I5)*(D$2:D<=J5));1);"") See your sample sheet for both alternatives please.

This works like a charm. Learned a lot on the way. Thank you!!

Then, you may accept it as an "Answer" or upvote to help people searching for a similar problem in the future.

Thanks! I already accepted it as an answer, let me know if you cannot see that. Also I have another question related to your answer: If I wanted to take the sum of the quota (taking only into account the unique value in one month no matter how often it appears), how would that go? I wanted to advance your formula a bit to do what it's already doing, but instead take the sum of the quotas for all (while ignoring double values within a month). Does this make sense? See column P in the exercise..

First of all; you have accepted rockinfreakshow's post as an answer, not mine. Secondly; for your last question, you can go with this formula: =ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(INDEX(SPLIT(UNIQUE((MONTH(D2:D20) & "|" & IF(A2:A20=O5;F2:F20)));"|");;2))) for Susan where cell O5 is housing the text Susan. You can check your sample sheet where I've entered the formula in Column P . So, if you like this; you can at least upvote my original post above.

This is great! Thank you very much. Is there a possibility to use the date filter (cell I16 and J16)? Let's say I were to change these two cells to reflect only a certain time period, rather than just taking everything from my report (which is what your formula is doing)

Check  Columns R ~ AB in your sample sheet. The logic is, according to start and end dates in cells S2 and S3, the master table in Columns A ~ H is filtered in Columns R ~ AB. Then, in Columns AA  - AB the result data is displayed. Hopefully, you will UPVOTE my message this time by hitting the (^) button.

Hey Haluk! This is great, but it doesn't work for... I was looking for a way to use S2 and S2 in the formula, rather than filtering the whole report. I cannot use your result because in my actual example, my report is a data import from Salesforce that updates automatically. I pulling the result using the formula in a different tab that references that report. Which is why I want to use S2 and S3 as a filter in the formula.. Happy to upvote your answer though.

May be you can place the summary table in another sheet and the other stuff (Start - End dates and the result range i.e. Columns AA - AB in the main sheet.

OK..... see the formula in cell M16 in your sample sheet. I hope this will solve your problem.

Yes and no. When you change the filter to show January till March (for example), your formula is returning #N/A... For some reason it's only returning a value when my filter dates show the full year.. it's weird

Yes, there is a problem with dates..... May be local formatting, may be something else. I've to go out now.....

Can you check your sample sheet?


You may try:
=index(xlookup(J5:J10&K3,C:C&D:D,F:F,))


